# How can I remove special characters in values that in list of Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove all the '/api/1/employees/' and /api/1/seats/ from the python dictionary. What is the easiest way to do so. My dictionary is looking like this at the moment -

```
dict1 = {5051: ['/api/1/employees/4027', '5051', '/api/1/seats/19014'], 5052: ['/api/1/employees/4048', '5052', '/api/1/seats/19013'], 5053: ['/api/1/employees/4117', '5053', '/api/1/seats/19012'], 5054: ['/api/1/employees/15027', '5054', '/api/1/seats/9765']}
```

I am expecting below dict

```
dict1 = {5051: ['4027', '5051', '19014'], 5052: ['4048', '5052', '19013'], 5053: ['4117', '5053', '19012'], 5054: ['15027', '5054', '9765']}
```

Comment: Is it a possibility that there might be a "/" at the end?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
dict1 = {k: [s.rsplit("/", 1)[-1] for s in v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works. The idea is to try to convert the entry to `int` and if we fail - split the entry and return last element

```
data = {5051: ['/api/1/employees/4027', '5051', '/api/1/seats/19014'],
         5052: ['/api/1/employees/4048', '5052', '/api/1/seats/19013'],
         5053: ['/api/1/employees/4117', '5053', '/api/1/seats/19012'],
         5054: ['/api/1/employees/15027', '5054', '/api/1/seats/9765']}

def get_int(value):
    try:
        x = int(value)
        return value
    except ValueError:
        return value.split('/')[-1]
data = {k: [get_int(vv) for vv in v] for k,v in data.items()}
print(data)
```

output

```
{5051: ['4027', '5051', '19014'], 5052: ['4048', '5052', '19013'], 5053: ['4117', '5053', '19012'], 5054: ['15027', '5054', '9765']}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the regex as below

```
import re

regex = r"[0-9][0-9]+"
dict1 = {5051: ['/api/1/employees/4027', '5051', '/api/1/seats/19014'],
         5052: ['/api/1/employees/4048', '5052', '/api/1/seats/19013'],
         5053: ['/api/1/employees/4117', '5053', '/api/1/seats/19012'],
         5054: ['/api/1/employees/15027', '5054', '/api/1/seats/9765']}

for i in dict1:
    dict1[i] = [re.findall(regex, j)[0] if len(re.findall(regex, j)) >= 1 else j for j in dict1[i]]

print(dict1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply following regex to achieve desired results

```
regex = r"[0-9][0-9]+"
```